# Changes in XML tree using Elementtree do not get updated

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying to insert a child element into a parent element but for some reason I cannot manage to update the tree in order to write a file containing the child element I just created. Can anyone please let me know what I'm missing?

This is what I have

```
<text>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
</text>
```

And this is what I need

```
<text>
  <p>
    <s>
    </s>
  </p>


  <p>
    <s>
    </s>
  </p>
</text>
```

```html
tree = et.parse('/Users/missogra/Desktop/test/s_tagging/1.txt')
root = tree.getroot()
for element in root:
    if element.tag == 'p':
        p = et.Element("p")
        child = et.SubElement(p, "s" )
# How to update the new root from here?
```

Comment: better add a language tag like 'python'

Comment: You are right. I just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this code

```
p = et.Element("p")
child = et.SubElement(p, "s" )
```

is creating a new `<p>` element, which is not part of the tree, and attaching a subelement to it.  The  tree itself is left unchanged.

Attach the new subelement to the `<p>` element that you find in the tree instead.

```
>>> for elem in root:
...     if elem.tag == 'p':
...         ET.SubElement(elem, 's')
... 
<Element 's' at 0x7f7810b24e58>
<Element 's' at 0x7f780ffdf4f8>

>>> ET.tostring(root)
b'<text><p><s /></p><p><s /></p></text>'
```